# \environment Definition with Parameter

Tags: environments, arguments

I digged around and found no answer to the following problem: I defined the environment myroman but using I failed. It is not clear for me why.
%

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
   \usepackage{enumitem}
  \newenvironment{myroman}[1][label=\roman*)]%
        {\begin{enumerate}[#1]}
        {\end{enumerate}}
        %
\begin{document}

\begin{myroman}
    \item First
    \item Second
\end{myroman}  

\begin{myroman}[resume*] % not working
   \item Third
   \item etc
\end{myroman}
        %
This is working:
        %
 \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)]
     \item one
      \item two
 \end{enumerate}

 \begin{enumerate}[resume*] 
    \item three
     \item four
  end{enumerate}
```

\end{document}

Comment: Good question, but you have some typos/omissions in there that prevent compilation

Comment: `enumitem` package documentation, p. 6: the `resume` option acts *locally*; “if you want global resuming, see next section on series”.

Comment: Ups, this I missed. Now I understood it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define a new list, for this.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myroman}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myroman,1]{label=\roman*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{myroman}
\item First

\item Second
\end{myroman}  

\begin{myroman}[resume*]
\item Third

\item etc
\end{myroman}

\end{document}
```

[image]